# Dropping XML message

Tags: javascript, http, post, xmlhttprequest

More than a week I'm trying to create communication between javascript(running on node.js) clientside script and WCF(SOAP) service.

Communication is throught: XML, POST method

```
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml; charset=utf-8');
```

URL and XML which I'm sending to service is defined as:

```
soapRequest('http://winserver:8735/ReportsListsService', 
    `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Header>
      <Action s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">http://tempuri.org/IReportsListsService/GetClients</Action>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body>
      <GetClients xmlns="http://tempuri.org/" />
    </s:Body>
  </s:Envelope>`);
```

This is my service, currently trying call simplest method GetClients

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using tt4t.Dispatching.ApplicationServer.Data.CommonData;

namespace tt4t.Dispatching.ApplicationServer.Data.Reports.Lists
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IReportsListsService : IMicroservice
    {
  [OperationContract]
        IEnumerable<Client> GetClients();
    }
}
```

But getting this error in chrome debug console

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><s:Body><s:Fault><faultcode>s:Client</faultcode><faultstring xml:lang="en-US">The incoming message contains a SOAP header representing the WS-Addressing 'Action', yet the HTTP transport is configured with AddressingVersion.None.  As a result, the message is being dropped.  If this is not desired, then update your HTTP binding to support a different AddressingVersion.</faultstring></s:Fault></s:Body></s:Envelope>
```

This error responds to this line of my xml request

```
   <s:Header>
              <Action s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">http://tempuri.org/IReportsListsService/GetClients</Action>
   </s:Header>
```

Full code: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50816079/session-id-between-javascript-and-services)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was missing

```
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('SOAPAction', "http://tempuri.org/IReportsListsService/GetClients");
```